# How can I filter 'Get-EC2ImageByName' to get the latest stable AMI-ID (not-rc)?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, aws-powershell

I've been successfully gathering the AMI ID via `Get-EC2ImageByName`, but I am trying to determine a method to pull latest "not-rc" AMI.

I currently run:

```
Get-EC2ImageByName -Names *amzn-ami-pv*x86_64*ebs* - | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "ImageId" -First 1
```

It gives me:

```
ami-978639e4
```

When I run:

```
Get-EC2ImageByName -Names *amzn-ami-pv*x86_64*ebs*
```

The first 2 entries are:

```
Architecture        : x86_64
BlockDeviceMappings : {/dev/sda1}
CreationDate        : 2016-02-27T22:30:03.000Z
Description         : Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03.rc-0 x86_64 PV EBS
Hypervisor          : xen
ImageId             : ami-978639e4
ImageLocation       : amazon/amzn-ami-pv-2016.03.rc-0.x86_64-ebs
ImageOwnerAlias     : amazon
ImageType           : machine
KernelId            : aki-52a34525
Name                : amzn-ami-pv-2016.03.rc-0.x86_64-ebs
OwnerId             : 137112412989
Platform            : 
ProductCodes        : {}
Public              : True
RamdiskId           : 
RootDeviceName      : /dev/sda1
RootDeviceType      : ebs
SriovNetSupport     : 
State               : available
StateReason         : 
Tags                : {}
VirtualizationType  : paravirtual

Architecture        : x86_64
BlockDeviceMappings : {/dev/sda1}
CreationDate        : 2016-02-10T22:22:22.000Z
Description         : Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09.2 x86_64 PV EBS
Hypervisor          : xen
ImageId             : ami-a93484da
ImageLocation       : amazon/amzn-ami-pv-2015.09.2.x86_64-ebs
ImageOwnerAlias     : amazon
ImageType           : machine
KernelId            : aki-52a34525
Name                : amzn-ami-pv-2015.09.2.x86_64-ebs
OwnerId             : 137112412989
Platform            : 
ProductCodes        : {}
Public              : True
RamdiskId           : 
RootDeviceName      : /dev/sda1
RootDeviceType      : ebs
SriovNetSupport     : 
State               : available
StateReason         : 
Tags                : {}
VirtualizationType  : paravirtual
```

I am trying to ignore the "rc" entry, and pick up the first AMI ID without "rc" in the name, or otherwise just the first "not rc" AMI ID.
In this example, the AMI-ID I want is:

```
ami-a93484da
```

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this without using "`-Skip 1`"?
(I am avoiding the use of "`-Skip 1`" because I am trying to make the script repeatable, for example if there are 2 or more "rc" releases.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just to update, I think the main issue is that I am **trying to gather this:** 
`amzn-ami-pv-2015.09.2.x86_64-ebs`
**Not this:** 
`amzn-ami-pv-2016.03.rc-0.x86_64-ebs`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming none of the other parts of the name change, you can use a regular expression to future-proof against incremented "rc-*digits*" values.  You can use this expression:

```
".rc-\d+."
```

This expression examines for the string ".rc-*digits*." anywhere in your string, where *digits* can be one or more digits.  From there, you can sort and filter for the desired output.

Below is a quick, live test, where I do the following:

- Get Images matching the name you supplied.
- Pipe the results to Where-Object (alias: ?) and filter out results with `-notmatch`, where I'm explicitly looking for results that do not match my expression.
- Sort by most recent AMI CreationDate. (this assumes that newer releases are launched later)
- Select ImageId, Name, and CreationDate to be output.
- Wrap the entire expression in `@()` to force output as a collection, and then retrieve the first item in that collection by specifying `[0]`.

**Example:**

```
PS C:/> @(Get-EC2ImageByName -Names "amzn-ami-pv*x86_64*ebs*" | `
Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch ".rc-\d+." } | `
Sort CreationDate -Desc | `
Select ImageId, Name, CreationDate)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
ImageId             Name                                    CreationDate
-------             ----                                    ------------
ami-d4f7ddbe        amzn-ami-pv-2015.09.2.x86_64-ebs        2016-02-10T22:21:22.000Z
```